# net use x: https://server/path vs new-psDrive x https://server/path

Tags: powershell, filesystems, drive

I am able to map a network path with the console command

```
net use x: https://some.server.xy/path/to/directory
```

However, when I tried to map the network drive in PowerShell (before I assigned it with `net use x: ...`) with

```
 new-psDrive v fileSystem https://some.server.xy/path/to/directory
```

I got the error message

> new-psDrive : The specified drive root "https://some.server.xy/path/to/directory" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.

Apparantly, my assumption that those two commands would have the same effect was wrong.

The question is: what is PowerShell's equivalent for using `net use ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [**Stack Exchange**](https://serverfault.com): [Map Network Drive to a WebDAV Server via PowerShell](https://serverfault.com/a/690340):

---

Here is a working example of me mounting the Sysinternals WebDAV site to my S: drive:

```
[String]$WebDAVShare = '\\live.sysinternals.com\Tools'
New-PSDrive -Name S -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $WebDAVShare
```

Notice you need to use the UNC format, not the `http://` prefix.

Also you need to make sure that the WebClient service is running on your computer.

If you wanted to confirm that a server supports WebDAV, you could do:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest http://live.sysinternals.com -Method Options).Headers.DAV
```

And if that returns something like `1,2,3` then the server supports various versions of WebDAV. (Although the server administrator may have disallowed the Options verb.)